# Failed installation of Archive::Extract with Cpan

Tags: perl, windows-10

I have installed ActivePerl in order to run a bioinformatic tool.
after running the tool on Windows PowerShell I got this message:

> Perl module Archive::Extract (in core since 2007-07-07) is not installed on this machine!
>   Perl modules are available for download at http://www.cpan.org/
>
> If you have CPAN installed try the following:  cpan  install
>   Archive::Extract  exit
>
> If you are on Mac or Unix you should run cpan with sudo:  sudo cpan 
>   install Archive::Extract  exit

So I tried to install it:

```
cpan
install Archive::Extract
```

and got this:

> "C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
>   t/01_Archive-Extract.t .. # Older versions of Archive::Zip may cause File::Spec warnings
>   See bug #19713 in rt.cpan.org. It is safe to ignore them
>   t/01_Archive-Extract.t .. 87/?

As I'm not adept at this I thought that I should try to install again the **Archive::Zip**

```
install Archive::Zip
```

but I got :

> t/25_traversal.t .............. 1/41
>      Failed test 'Tree extraction aborted'
>      at t/25_traversal.t line 97.
>             got: '0'
>        expected: '2'
>    Looks like you failed 1 test of 41.
>   t/25_traversal.t .............. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
>   Failed 1/41 subtests
>           (less 32 skipped subtests: 8 okay)
>
> ### Test Summary Report
>
> t/25_traversal.t            (Wstat: 256 Tests: 41 Failed: 1)
>     Failed test:  16
>     Non-zero exit status: 1
>   Files=25, Tests=346, 18 wallclock secs ( 0.19 usr +  0.13 sys =  0.31 CPU)
>   Result: FAIL
>   Failed 1/25 test programs. 1/346 subtests failed.
>   dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'test_dynamic'

Could you please explain what's the particular problem in order to understand it and how can I solve it?

I don't know if it's a naive question as I have just started learning about command line tools, Linux, Perl etc.

Comment: Exactly what version of ActivePerl did you install?  And, what version of Windows are you on?

Comment: Windows Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.285)
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Comment: Could you provide the full output, please? (You might have to use an external site like pastebin.com)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I haven't used pastedin again, is it proper? 
https://pastebin.com/qWc5arxW

Comment: If you're going to stay with ActivePerl, you might want to subscribe to some of their Perl-specific mailings lists.  I used them heavily when I was first learning Perl on Windows eighteen years ago.

Comment: @ikegami Found anything useful from my full output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active Perl uses the ppm script to install modules, mixing this with cpan can cause the problems you have seen above. You may find that using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) works better for you as this comes with a c compiler that will allow you to install non pure Perl modules from cpan

Comment: https://www.activestate.com/activeperl/ppm-perl-modules - neat, as I've never used ActivePerl specifically, I'd never heard of PPM - nice!

Comment: Everything you say about Strawberry Perl applies to ActivePerl too.